# Maximum covered loss

Tags: calculus, statistics, probability-distributions

Aggregate loss S follows a compound distribution. The primary distribution is ${PN}(20) $ and the secondary distribution is $U(0,5)$. If the policies are modified with a deductible of d=1 and a maximum covered loss of u=4, compute the mean and the variance of the modified aggregate loss $\tilde S$

---

I think that

$N \sim PN(20)$

$E(N)=V(N)=20=\lambda$

$X ~\sim U(0,5)$

$E(X)=2.5 $ $V(X)=25/12$

$1-F_x(d)=(b-d)/b$

Poison parameter for the modified frequency distribution is $\lambda \frac{b-d}{b}$

$\lambda \frac{b-d}{b}=20\frac{4-1}{5}=16$

How can I find this mean and variance? Help me.

Thanks.

Comment: what is modified aggregate loss?